# Show that if $\sigma = \frac {z(1 - \pi)}{x} < 0$ then $- \pi \sigma = \frac {- \pi z (1 - \pi)}{x} > (1 - \pi)$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to understand a published economic paper and can't figure out the following steps:

$\pi$ and $1-\pi$ are probabilities, z and x are two long terms that I have summarised for simplification, with $z<0$ and $x>0$.

The authors say that if 
$$\sigma = \frac {z(1 - \pi)}{x} < 0$$ 
then (Step 1)
$$ \frac {-\pi z} {x} > 1$$ 
which means that (Step 2)
$$- \pi \sigma = \frac {- \pi z (1 - \pi)}{x} > (1 - \pi)$$
holds.
Step 2 is obvious to me, but I just can't figure out how Step 1 works and would really appreciate any hints! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably have to explicit some relations between $x,z$: if $x = -z=1$ it is false...

Comment: I saw now that $x = y - \pi z > 0$ where $y$ is again a long term summarised and $y<0$. Does that help? I still don't see how Step 1 works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x > 0$, so $\frac{-\pi z}{x} > 1 \iff -\pi z > x = y -\pi z \iff 0 > y$, which is true. This doesn't use the fact that $\sigma < 0$ directly (but that $x>0>y$).